# Similar source for Cardano

Tags: wallet, address, python

I want to generate public and private keys with an address. I found [this](https://github.com/meherett/python-hdwallet) repository but it doesn't support Cardano. Does anybody know any similar source?

Answer (score 1):

Cardano uses Bip32-Ed25519 standard for deriving keys and uses bech32 for encoding keys/addresses. I'm not aware of any native python libraries for doing the key derivation, but you could wrap cardano-addresses as long as it's in the path as I do here in adawallet: https://github.com/input-output-hk/adawallet/blob/ae8ddbb164b9b95037cd2d7e795e9926dc0f5df6/adawallet/adawallet/lib.py#L326-L332.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/integrate-cardano/creating-wallet-faucet/) should help. You can use `cardano-wallet` and `cardano-cli` for wallet and addresses management.

Comment: The thing is I don't wanna run a full node or using cli. I want to do all the processes in python.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-addresses) should give you all you need to start generating keys for Cardano in your language of choice. Also check out CIP-1852 and CIP-19